# what is the fully connected layer in googlent/Resnet50/Resnet101/inception v2 and v3

Tags: matlab, resnet, vgg-net

I'm working on matlab and try to use the pretrained model cited above as feature extractor. In Alexnet and vggnet the fully connected layer is clear which named 'fc7' but in googlenet/resnet50/resnet101/inception v2 v3 it is not clear, could someone guide me? also what is the size of features in these models because in alexnet for example is 4096?

Answer (score 0):

In any CNN, the fully connected layer can be spotted looking at the end of the network, as it processes the features extracted by the Convolutional Layer. If you access 
`net.Layers`, you see that matlab calls the fully connected layer "Fully Connected" (which in ResNet 50 is fc1000). It is also followed by a softmax and a classification output.
The size of the classification layers depends on the Convolutional layer used for features extraction. In alexnet, different fully connected layers are stacked (fc6,fc7,fc8). I think that you can find the matrix extracted (therefore the features), by flattening the output before the first fully connected layer. In this case before fc1000

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think that "fc1000" is the layer of classification. I need the layer that has in its output  features for example in alexnet we extract the feature by using activations like this:  I = readimage(ImagesTrain,i);
                                I = imresize(I,[227,227]);
                                Features = activations(net,I,layer);

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding, you can use this approach in any point of the CNN. In the case of Alexnet, you used it between two layers of the final Feed-Forward Net used for classification. Generally the features extracted are at the end of the Convolutional Layer.

Comment: You are probably making reference to:
https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/activations.html?searchHighlight=activations&s_tid=doc_srchtitle
Try looking at this example: https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/examples/visualize-activations-of-a-convolutional-neural-network.html

Comment: Thank you very much enrico_ay for these useful links